# How can I control the title on a Google Chrome tab?

Tags: weebly

In putting my website together using Weebly (I know, but it's for compatability) I have noticed that when Chrome opens a new tab the title does not match the content. These titles seem rather random: sometimes it's a word on that page or image, sometimes it's from another page or image, sometimes it seems completely random. Is there a way to control that?

Answer (score 0):

You can set it below:

```
Go to the Pages > SEO Settings > Page Title
```

Alternatively the html tag is:

```
<title>Title goes here</title>
```